# unexpected react component state value change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the `state` value but first I have loaded it in another `var`and after changes made on the new `var` it is going to `setState` and update the original `state` value. but unexpectedly changes made to the temp `var` already changes the `component` `state` value!

```
var postData = this.state.postData;
postData.likes = postData.likes + 1;
console.log(postData.likes, this.state.postData.likes);
```

the `console.log` values:
    (1, 1)
    (2, 2)
    ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `postData` is an object, don't save it directly in another variable since that will create a reference to the one in the state, not a copy. And if it's a reference, changing one will change the other cos they're both pointing to the same object.

Make a copy of it first"

```
    var postData = Object.assign({}, this.state.postData)
```

and then change it. Then when you're done, use `setState({postData})`

Answer (score 1):

you should never ever mutate state, always use setState, and for copying object user spread notation "..."

```
this.setState(((prevState) => ({
  postData:{
    ...prevState.postData,
    likes: prevState.postData.likes + 1,

  }
});
```

Comment: This is the incorrect way of updating state as it often leads to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @AnhPham and how so?

Comment: Refer to the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: now I see what you mean, but unless you are mindlessly updating state from multiple places, its should be fine, but fixed it for you ;-)

Comment: But still you shouldn't be doing it that way

Comment: no reason not to, I would understand that you mind the previous version, cause this state could be different at the time, but now? no reason not to. and if you just that something is wrong, you arent contributing nor helping, either state what you think is wrong or dont bother at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178202/discussion-between-anh-pham-and-lukas-gibo-vaic).

Comment: What if the person posting has multiple updaters for states in his/her app, perhaps the previous version maybe work out for him/her. But the uncertainty does not exist on StackOverflow.

Comment: thats why I have rewritten it to user save version with prevState, there isnt much safer way

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ES2018 spread notation like `var postData = {...this.state.postData};` to clone the object and manipulate it before assigning back to state.

Comment: yes, actually this one works too. thanks for your comment.